Is there another more natural way to say "do it with excitement"?
I asked my daughter to dance but she seemed to dance in a way that lacks enthusiasm.
Can I say to her "do it with excitement" in this situation?
Or do we have other more natural expressions?

"Excitedly" is a word, but it may not be quite what you want. You are asking your daughter to show, or perhaps communicate excitement in her dance.

It may be hard to force a child to do something with an anthiusiasm they don't feel.


Do it with enthusiasm (or passion).

is fine.  We could also say

Do it with zest (or gusto).

Collins Dictionary defines gusto and gives a similar example:

vigorous enjoyment


Hers was a minor part, but she played it with gusto.


"Con brio" as my music teacher used to say.
